# Connecting Next.js API routes to AWS Aurora V2

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-aurora-serverless

Is it possible to connect Next.js API routes to AWS Aurora DB version 2. I can do this with Aurora version 1 as it has the data api, but V2 has removed the data API. Also, I am using a serverless Aurora db.

Is this possible?